# How to draw two polylines on top of each other in Google Maps with two different colors between two locations

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, polyline

I have two locations and I need to draw 2 polylines on top of each other (with some spacing) between these locations. Polylines have 2 different width and color. **Smaller** **polyline needs to be in the center of the bigger one.**

The issue is: in the zoomed out level it looks correct. However, when you zoom in, their position change. You can see corresponding images below:

[Zoomed out image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mHc7.png) - *Zoom level is 17.74781*

[Zoomed in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWR84.png) - *Zoom level is 21.0*

Code snippet:

```
// White polyline

 val outlineColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white)
 val outlineThicknessInPx = context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.outline_thickness) -> 12dp
 val outlineGapInPx = context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.outline_gap) -> 4dp

 map.addPolyline( 
    PolylineOptions()
     .addAll(latLongList)
     .width(outlineThicknessInPx)
     .color(outlineColor)
     .zIndex(1f)
     .pattern(listOf(Dot(), Gap(outlineGapInPx)))
 )

// Black polyline

val polylineColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black)
val polylineThicknessInPx = context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.polyline_thickness) -> 8dp
val polylineStartGapInPx = context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.polyline_start_gap) -> 2dp
val polylineEndGapInPx = context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.polyline_end_gap) -> 6dp

map.addPolyline(
   PolylineOptions()
    .addAll(latLongList)
    .width(polylineThicknessInPx)
    .color(polylineColor)
    .zIndex(2f)
    .pattern(listOf(Gap(polylineStartGapInPx), Dot(), Gap(polylineEndGapInPx)))
)
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem specifically but in the process found an issue with alignment of the duo of patterns (outer,inner), specifically introduced by the `Dot` which evidently has an implied padding which is _proportional_ to the stroke width.  Because of this, using the parameters provided, the inner dot slowly precedes the outer dot (which is however not evident in your zoom-out snap over the short span).  For me, this can be corrected by modifying one of the input parameters `polylineEndGapInPx` from 6. to 6.575.

Comment: This effectively cancels the accumlated error every n dots (I believe the implementation is using truncation).  But that's not the only variable in that all of the pixel values are in screen pixels and polyline pixel settings are unaffected by zoom but leads to a question of rendering implementation when mapping a point to the screen.  One additional parameter that could be useful is the device screen dimension in pixels.  I can provide more info (and drawings) but being that I cannot reproduce your issue I was reluctant to do so.